# Getting client ip from local LAN through internet

Tags: php, ip

The thing is that in my institute we all have the same global IP, now I have a site in which we need to identify users uniquely for the votes in a polling system... otherwise we use cookies to identify them, which they easily delete to rig the polls. 
the local IP of the site is 192.168.1.69 so when someone comments from there we get their client address, but I need to edit this code so that it checks whether the website (not IP) is being accessed from our institute or not, if yes, then the client address should be stored by maybe pinging the local IP. So please help me out.

Here is some of the relevant code

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
else 
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
```

Comment: You'll want to tag this as PHP

Comment: 'regular' login system is the only way to 'guarantee' unique votes. i would never use ip for this

Comment: ip can be spoofed, inaccurate, etc. cookies ofc can be cleared. even with a login system, creating multiple accounts can't really be curbed. the only real way of restricting to unique votes is to validate that a person is who they say they are before you give them out a valid login/token to vote with. when i say validate, i don't mean over the internet.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would really not use an (just) IP based login system. Read the comments above.

Hmmm.. Even after reading your question multiple times I'm not sure if I understand your question right. But if I understand it right there may be an technical 'restriction' too:

What I understood:

You have a website, lets say www.xyz.com. Then you have a local network with many clients that access the internet over a NAT gateway.

You are planning:

If the NAT router's IP (means a client from inside your institute) is recognized as client IP on www.xyz.com, than you plan to make 'pingback' to get the local clients IP from inside your institutes network?

If I understand you right, then it is not possible because it defeats the principles of NAT. The meaning of NAT is (in easy words) to **hide** local IP's from internet address space.

As restrictions made to be broken by programmers ;) there will be ways to make that 'pingback' with methods called NAT traversal. But I would advice you not implementing an IP based login system. Because:

- thats unsafe because IP's can be spoofed easily. (You could just disconnect one machine and use its IP address)
- what is with DHCP? what is if IP's should change once?

Note: **an IP isn't a sufficient ID for logins**